# Scraping RSS XML Feed

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape an RSS feed every hour to run sentiment analysis on headlines of stocks I own. However, I am having issues scraping the rss xml feed. I have tried packages: `httr`, `XML`, `RCurl` and `tidyRSS`.

I have previously used these packages to successfully scrape xml code, so I am struggling to diagnose the issue. From another answer, I tried dropping the `s` in `https`, but no success.

Code with corresponding errors:

```
my_url <- "https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?symbol=BAC"

## Failure when receiving data from the peer
feed <- httr::GET(url = my_url)

## Error: 1: failed to load external entity
feed <- XML::xmlTreeParse(my_url, isURL = TRUE) 

## error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
feed <- RCurl::getURL(url = my_url)

##   Attempt to fetch feed resulted in an error: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle): Failure when receiving data from the peer
feed <- tidyRSS::tidyfeed(feed = my_url)
```

I am using R - 4.1.1 with all mentioned packages updated to latest version.

Comment: I think you may have better success using the api interface and retrieving the JSON results from here: `jsonlite::fromJSON( "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/news/topic/articlebysymbol?q=bac|stocks&offset=0&limit=10&fallback=true" )`

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e! This gets me a solid starting point. I would also like the description from the RSS feed. I tried to find the api documentation but only found references to the `dataondemand` api which doesn't look the same. Is there documentation you can point me to?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a reference, it is generally reversed engineered from the network traffic.  I was having trouble accessing the RSS feed so I was looking to see what files are downloaded from this page: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/bac/news-headlines (see the Network tab of developer tools) when loaded.  Found the JSON link to the news headlines.

Comment: Ahh I see. I too was looking through the dev tools but struggling to connect any dots on how the data was generated. Googling proved to be unfruitful. I am very grateful for the previous code you gave. I think I can leverage the code and try to scrape the first paragraph or two of the corresponding the url's returned. Again, thank you @Dave2e.